# splitting three columns with different contents across a page without mixing

Tags: multicol

I wish to create a three column document spanning multiples pages. The contents of columns A, B and C are very different, and should not be mixed up, i.e. the contents of column A should not end up in the second column. This isn't a table either in that there is no common row alignment between the contents of the three columns.

How can I format the document in this manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `paracol`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}
  \begin{paracol}{3}
  \kant
  \switchcolumn   %% second column
  \kant
  \switchcolumn   %% third column
  \kant
  \end{paracol}
\end{document}
```

[image]